# Easter breakfast in Chennai

Tags: india, food-and-drink, festivals, religion

Where can I get a traditional Easter breakfast in Chennai? Is it possible to get it in some sort of restaurant that caters to foreign tourists?

For those that don't know, it usually consists of boiled eggs, cooked ham, radishes and spring onions.

Comment: What part of the world is that from, then? Look for a community from wherever this is a traditional dish.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find a traditional Easter breakfast in India -

- Number of people (in terms of percentage) celebrating Easter is less.
- And then people preparing/following the tradition Easter cuisine will be much less in India

Answer (score 1):

The Verahndah is a good one, as it is European as well.

CUISINE: Beverages, Continental, European, Italian, North Indian, South Indian

Services

24 Hrs Open
Non Vegetarian
Serves Liquor
Accepts Major Credit Cards
A/C
Dine In

On 'Buzzintown', user rating is 4.5